# Redirect traffic from www. to store.

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to make changes on .htaccess to redirect traffic that is in the form `www.mysite.com/products/product_id` or `www.mysite.com/items/item_id` to `store.mysite.com/products/product_id` or `store.mysite.com/items/item_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect

- mysite.com/products/*
- mysite.com/items/*

to

- store.mysite.com/products/*
- store.mysite.com/items/*

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(products|items) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://store.mysite.com/$1 [NC,L,QSA,R]
```